# Вывод товаров в ubercart3

Tags: drupal, циклы

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
По дефолту `ubercart3` выводит товары через `views`, используя 2 цикла

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
<?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>
<?php print $item; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Я хотел бы вывести товары через один цикл. Помогите, пожалуйста